# display Sum of last column

Tags: php, mysql

- > Polish Diamond
  >   Information

  ```
  mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); mysql_select_db("basic");

  $order = "select * from polish ";       $result=mysql_query($order);


  $a="select sum(total) from polish"; $b=mysql_query($a);


   ?>
  <?php echo "Polish Diamonds Information: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ";
        echo "<a href='home.html'>Go to main page
        <br><br>";

  ?>



  <table border="1" style="width:50%">

           <tr>
              <th><b>ID</b></th>
              <th><b> Name</b></th>
              <th> <b>Selection</b><br>(40000)</th>
              <th><b>Super Deluxe<br>(35000)</b></th>
              <th><b>1<br>(30000)</b></th>
              <th><b>2<br>(25000)</b></th>
              <th><b>3<br>(20000)</b></th>
              <th><b>4<br>(10000)</b></th>
              <th><b>Total Payment</b></th>
              <th><b>Days</b></th>

                   </tr>



      <?php        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )       {
          echo "<tr>
              <td>".$row['id']."</td>
              <td>".$row['name']."</td>
              <td>".$row['c_sel']."</td>
              <td>".$row['c_sdel']."</td>
              <td>".$row['c_1']."</td>
              <td>".$row['c_2']."</td>
              <td>".$row['c_3']."</td>
              <td>".$row['c_4']."</td>
              <td>".$row['total']."</td>
              <td>".$row['day']."</td>
           </tr>";         }

  ?>    </html>
  ```

Comment: thanks raju for editing code.

Comment: i want last column totals sum ..how to get it.

Comment: sum of days in last column??

Comment: You should define what sum you want where more (best with an example output you want. atm its a bit confusing as you already created a sum $b  but from the table you made it doesnt make sense that THAT sum is displayed. So the question is: What sum do you want to display where? As currently one can only take guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this loop

```
$sum_val=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )       {
    echo "<tr>
        <td>".$row['id']."</td>
        <td>".$row['name']."</td>
        <td>".$row['c_sel']."</td>
        <td>".$row['c_sdel']."</td>
        <td>".$row['c_1']."</td>
        <td>".$row['c_2']."</td>
        <td>".$row['c_3']."</td>
        <td>".$row['c_4']."</td>
        <td>".$row['total']."</td>
        <td>".$row['day']."</td>
     </tr>";
     $sum_val+=$row['total'];
     }

     echo"Last column total= $sum_val";
```

Comment: Now this query (select sum(total) from polish) is no need

Comment: Thanks @ ManiMuthuPandi...i got it.

Comment: the query he made made no sense at all anyway as it was done outside the loop and thus only done once although he wants it "in" the last column according to what he wrote. Asked for clarification in a comment on the main question as to what sum he wants where (how he formualted it it sounded like he wants a sum being displayed per line)

Comment: ah ok then it was the correct interpretation. @john if that is the answer that helped please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

you cat try by this way

```
$order = "select *, sum(c_sel+c_sdel+c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4) as total from polish GROUP BY id "; $result=mysql_query($order);
```